# SQL match also array in other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table A and a table B which contains a foreign key to A and another column which stores country names.

Let's say I have a row with ID 1 in A, and some rows in B with reference to A row ID 1 and another column with a country name.

Let's also say that I have a row with ID 2 in A, and some rows in B with reference to A row ID 2 and other countries.

Can I compare these two rows in table A based on matches found in table B?
I want, having row 1, to be able to select with a MySQL query the second row, if a) Some of the countries found in row 1 reference exist in row 2, and b) All of the countries found in row 1 exist in row 2.

I could do it of course with multiple sql queries, but I wonder if there is an inner join trick.

Comment: Using some actual example data instead of "let's say"s will really improve your question.

Comment: Showing your tested method of accomplishing it with multiple queries would also be helpful in clarifying what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User subqueries:

```
select * from
(select A.ID from A inner join B on A.ID = B.F_ID) T1
inner join 
(select A.ID from A inner join B on A.ID = B.F_ID) T2
on T1.ID = T2.ID
```